# How to deal with one or more races

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a clients, clientraces, and a globalcodes table (where the race name is stored)

I'm putting together a demographics report, and I want to have (if applies) each separate race in it's own column, and one record, versus having 2 records per client.  I've done this before it's just been a while, I remember using row_number() over and basically the race would shw up in the column if there was another one, if not the columns remained null.  If there is a better way I would also love to know this!

I would like it to look like this if possible

Susie Smith  f  56y    white     asian

not like:
Susie Smith  f  56y    white
Susie Smith  f  56y    asian

thanks in advance

Comment: do you like one column per race or all races in one column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a pivot. Here's an example:

```
create table #test (name varchar(50), gender varchar(3), dateofbirth datetime, race varchar(50))

Insert into #test 
Values ('Susie Smith', 'f', '10/10/1940', 'white'),('Susie Smith', 'f', '10/10/1940', 'asian')


select *
from #test
PIVOT (max(race) for race in ([white],[asian])) as pv
```

Comment: Why did you use that subquery instead of simply `from #test`?

Comment: I was writing over an old example I did and it didn't need to be there. I edited it. Thanks for catching!